# Keep only unique items in list C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of string C# like this:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "D" };
```

I would like to keep only the unique items in that list, and all items that appear multiple times removed.

In this example it would be the items "A" and "D" left, after all duplicates are removed.

Comment: If you're removing duplicates shouldn't the list read "A", "B", "C", "D"

Comment: I want to remove all duplicate value too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "D" };

    list = list.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

You can use linq to do this.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, as it also considers making a new list, which OP also stated.

Answer (score 9):

What about this:

```
var tmp = myList.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 1);
```

This will just return those entries that occur exactly once. Entries which have duplicates are not returned.

Now simply flatten that list of groups into something like this:

```
var result = tmp.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey look someone understood the question

Comment: Oh. I thought the question is wrong. the question is not well phrased.

Comment: Look my answer and you will see. This code will return IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>

Comment: @mybirthname probably could have sufficed as a comment or edit instead of a new answer to be fair

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre you can see the post time of both answers.

Comment: @mybirthname my bad, must have got lost in the 5 answers that were posted within about 3 seconds of each other!

Answer (score 4):

```
list.GroupBy(x => x) //group the items together with themselves as the key
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1) // select only those groups with only one element
    .Select(g => g.Key) // get the key out (.First() and .FirstOrDefault()
                        // would also work in this case, .Key tends to be a tiny bit faster).
    .ToList() // create a new list (if really necessary,
              // if you can skip this step do and things will be faster).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "D" };
        var NewList = list.Except(list.GroupBy(i => i).Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
                                    .Select(ss => ss.FirstOrDefault()))
                                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "D"};
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            string x = list.ElementAt(i);
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                if (list.ElementAt(j).Equals(x))
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count>1)
                    {
                        list.RemoveAll(y => y.Equals(x));
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

try this...
end of the codes the list contains only "A" "D"

Comment: There are already many answers to this question, including at least three that answer the question better, more efficiently, and with better explanation than this.